# Excel formula for conditional formatting when text appears more than 3 times in row. Need to highlight the No cells

Tags: excel

Trying to figure a Excel formula for conditional formatting when 'No' appears more than 3 times in row. Need to highlight the No cells

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you have the "NO" values in column A starting from the cell A0. In HOME Tab, choose Conditional Formatting -> Manage Rules -> New Rule. Choose "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" in Select a Rule Type. Enter the following formula in the Format values where this formula is true:

```
=OR(AND(A1="NO",OFFSET(A1,1,0)="NO",OFFSET(A1,2,0)="NO"), IF(ROW(A1)>1,AND(A1="NO",OFFSET(A1,-1,0)="NO",OFFSET(A1,1,0)="NO"),FALSE),IF(ROW(A1)>2,AND(A1="NO",OFFSET(A1,-1,0)="NO",OFFSET(A1,-2,0)="NO"),FALSE))
```

Click the Format button to choose the way to highlight the cells. Then click OK and go back to Conditional Formatting Rules Manager. Choose the cells that you want to format in the "Applies to" field. Then Apply.

The above formula returns true if there are a consecutive three "NO" cells.

Comment: I am still having issues with getting it to highlight.  My 'No' values start on D16 to I16.  Is there a way to use a count if formula (=SUM(COUNTIF(D16:I16,"no")) and then somehow figure how to add a formula to highlight the 'No cells"?

Comment: Try the following formula to highlight those "No" cells.

`=OR(COUNTIF(OFFSET(D16,0,0,1,3),"NO")=3,COUNTIF(OFFSET(D16,0,-1,1,3),"NO")=3,COUNTIF(OFFSET(D16,0,-2,1,3),"NO")=3)`

Note that when using conditional formatting, it checks for one single cell only. Each single "NO" cell may be highlighted for the following cases:

1. It is "NO" and two more "NO" on the right, OR;
2. It is "NO" and one "NO" on the left and one "NO" on the right, OR;
3. It is "NO" and two more "NO" on the left.

So the formula needs to handle these three cases.